# It gives me an error 404 Not Found Angular

Tags: angular, routes, url-routing

I have a login page and a home page on another, the problem is that in production if you do not go through the login you cannot go to the home, that is ... if I do a

```
ng build --prod --base-href /project/
```

In production if I access `http://xx.xxx.xxx.x/project` it works, but if in the navigation bar I put `http://xx.xxx.xxx.x/project/home` or `http://xx.xxx.xxx.x/project/login` gives a not found 404

It also gives me this same error if I am in the login or in the home page and I reload the page, it makes me put the route again: `http://xx.xxx.xxx.x/project`

Go through the login to go to the home. This locally works well for me by doing an ng serve, but not in production.

My routing code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'login'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'config',
        component: ConfigComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into app.module.ts

```
import { PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
// In providers
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}]
```